# How to get all attributes associated with its object class under each basedns from LDAP via Softerra?

Tags: ldap, ldap-query

I have a requirement in which I need to get all the `attribute types` associated with each `object classes` under each `baseDN`(s).

Using softerra, I can get all the attribute types under specific object classes via schema viewer:
[image]

but I also need to determine from which baseDN it is associated.

To sum up, I need to have the ff.
(1) Get all attribute types under each object class.
(2) Get all object class under each baseDN.

Can you please help me how to fulfill those needs?

Thank you!

Comment: Please Tell us more. What are you trying to accomplish? What you have tried and show logs or results and Read:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Apologies for the lack of content, I already revised it. Let me know if it already makes sense.

Comment: I am still not sure what you are asking. But to obtain all of the schema values from an LDAP server is dependent on the LDAP implementation. See if this helps: https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Query%20For%20Schema